# Rotate Point Cloud to Smallest Width

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have an array of points **`p1, p2, pn...`** which represent random coordinates of the form **R( x, y )** on a Cartesian plane.

I would like to rotate the points until the width of the cloud (x-position of rightmost point minus x-position or leftmost point) is as small as possible.

[image: Rotating a Point Cloud to the Smallest Width]

**Note:**

A key optimization can be made by representing the cloud as a convex polygon. No point inside the resulting convex polygon can be a left or rightmost point. <del>but I am unsure of how to construct it</del> Thanks to @AlexeyBurdin; I now realize what I need to construct is a [Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull):

[image: Point Cloud Abstracted Into a Polygon]

How can I determine the ideal rotation to minimize the point cloud's width?

Given the polygon, I have though about calculating the distances between every point and edge midpoint on the polygon, and rotating based on the slope of the line with the shortest length. However, I find this solution to be poor because it creates a problem with **NP** complexity, where I imagine a **P** solution exists.

Comment: Can we assume that there will be a vertical edge in that polygon, when rotated to a minimal width? If not, it can be rotated more to make the width less. I think it is the key point. Which gives $O(n^2)$ where $n$ is number of the polygon vertices (or edges). See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Computation) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/120589).

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin No, this cannot be assumed. The links were very useful. For now I will try and implement the approach in the liked answer. I'll add the convex hull link to the question; this is exactly what I was looking for.